# How can I create DataSet using U2 Toolkit for .NET’s Add-ins and Visual Studio 2010 DataSet Designer?

Tags: u2netdk

I want to use U2NETDK’s feature ‘U2 Database Add-ins for Visual Studio’ to create a DataSet and use in different.NET application.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to answer this question myself.

Download and Install U2NETDK v1.2.0 BETA

[image: Fig 1]

Confirm Installation using VS2010->Help->About

[image]

Confirm Installation using Control Panel->Programs Features

[image]

Start Visual Studio 2010. Go to View->Server Explorer->Add Connection. Go to ‘Change Data source’ Dialog. Select ‘U2 Database’

[image]

Fill the connection string. Test the connection. Select ‘OK’

[image]

U2 Connection will be added in Server Explore

[image]

Open VS2010 WinForm Application. Right Click on solution explorer and add new item.

[image]

Select Data->DataSet. Give a name, for example ‘Members_DataSet’. An empty DataSet Designer will be created
[image]

Now drap and drop ‘Member Table’ from Server Explorer into DataSet Designer. It creates a DataTable and  TableAdapter.  It generates code. Table Adapter contains CRUD Statements ( Select, Insert, Update and Delete)
[image]

You can Preview Data

[image]

Select ‘Preview Data’

[image]

Go to Data->Show Data Sources
[image]

You will see generated ‘Member Data Set’ in Data Source Window. You can drag and drop ‘Member Data Set’ into WinForm

[image]

Run the WinFrom Application
[image]

Comment: So you have raised and answered your own question ?

Comment: No. This is one of the question in 'u2netdk' tag. I have replied in such a way so that all U2 users can see it.